# Function argument gets incremented by itself without me changing it

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Ok, so I am trying to move a rectangle on the html5 canvas, and I created my function to do so. It gets a velocity argument, which it then increments to the position, like so (c is the canvas' context):

```
this.moveDown = function moveDown(velocity){
    requestAnimationFrame(moveDown);
    c.clearRect(posX, posY, width, height);
    posY += velocity;
    console.log(velocity);
    c.fillRect(posX, posY, width, height);
}
```

Afterwards I call it in another javascript file in order for it to work :

```
var rect1 = new spiel.Rectangle(10,10, 100,100, "#F0F0F0");
rect1.draw();
rect1.moveDown(1);
```

As you can see, it gets 1 as it's velocity, and should (with as much as I know) move the rectangle 1 pixel every iteration, right? the problem is, when I try to `console.log()` the velocity variable, this is what gets returned every iteration in the console:

[image: The result of the console.log(velocity)]

Apparently, the velocity variable is getting incremented every iteration. What is causing this? How can I fix this problem? Also, in the javascript file that I am calling the function, everything is wrapped in a window.load function if that could be the cause

```
window.onload = function(){

spiel.drawCanvas(800,600, "#FFF000");

var rect1 = new spiel.Rectangle(10,10, 100,100, "#F0F0F0");
rect1.draw();
rect1.moveDown(1);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` passes a high-resolution timer value to the function it calls. That's what you're seeing in `velocity`, because you've passed `moveDown` to rAF:

```
requestAnimationFrame(moveDown);
```

So the 1 you see at first is the one **you** call it with, but subsequently you're seeing the timer value rAF calls it with.

(Side note: You're unconditionally calling rAF to schedule a callback; presumably you'd have a stop condition in there somewhere?)

If you want it to keep getting 1, just use a wrapper function or `bind`:

Wrapper:

```
this.moveDown = function moveDown(velocity){
    // NOTE: This works because `moveDown` doesn't use `this`
    // If you need `this`, you'd have to do one of the many things to ensure it
    requestAnimationFrame(function() { // Presumably you'll have a stop condition on this?
        moveDown(velocity);
    });
    c.clearRect(posX, posY, width, height);
    posY += velocity;
    console.log(velocity);
    c.fillRect(posX, posY, width, height);
}
```

`bind`:

```
this.moveDown = function moveDown(velocity){
    // Handles `this`, in case the function ever changes to use it
    requestAnimationFrame(this.moveDown.bind(this, 1)); // Presumably you'll have a stop condition on this?
    c.clearRect(posX, posY, width, height);
    posY += velocity;
    console.log(velocity);
    c.fillRect(posX, posY, width, height);
}
```

Since the rAF callback can run 60 times/second, we might want to avoid creating a function *every* time, so:

```
this.moveDown = function moveDown(velocity){
    var handleMove = function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(handleMove); // Presumably you'll have a stop condition on this?
        c.clearRect(posX, posY, width, height);
        posY += velocity;
        console.log(velocity); // And probably remove this
        c.fillRect(posX, posY, width, height);
    }.bind(this); // *IF* you need `this`
    handleMove();
}
```